# ASP.NET form posting to classic ASP page without losing state

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp-classic

I have an an ASP.NET page that contains a form which when submitted, posts to a classic ASP page SaveToDatabase.asp whose responsibility is to save the form data to the database.

mypage.aspx:

```
<form name="mfyorm" id="myform" method="POST" action="SaveToDatabase.asp" runat="server"> 
...
</form>
```

SaveToDatabase.asp reads the posted values using request.form and uses ADO to save these to the database. The reason why classic ASP is used is for legacy reasons and would be too complex to migrate away from.

If for some reason the ASP page fails to save the data (e.g. due to a query timeout), it then outputs an error message. I also want to include a link alongside the message, which when clicked, will return the user back to the mypage.aspx (with the edited form) so that the user can retry the save operation.

The difficulty I'm encountering is how to get mypage.aspx to load it's previous state as I don't want the user to lose the unsaved changes. I guess I could pass the values retrieved from the request.form values in a query string when navigating back to mypage.aspx. It just seems a pain to have to repopulate all of the form values this way. Are there any other techniques that can be used to prevent loss of state?

Comment: Have to looked at running the classic ASP page in an iframe and having it call a JavaScript function in the parent ASP.Net page?  You might also want a timer in the ASP.Net page that fires if the ASP page fails to complete.  This way you will retain your ASP.Net page state.

Comment: You could also include a small `iframe` on your Classic ASP page with a blank page and `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900" />` in the header.  This will refresh the iframe every 15 minutes.  Just make sure it's out of the way somewhere and the same colour as the background of your main page.  It's a good idea to note that Meta refresh is frowned on in most cases.

Comment: To echo what others have suggested, you'll likely want to run the ASP code in a different frame, or perhaps a modal popup with a "processing" message. Depending on your layout, one or the other may look more presentable to your users. You may even tuck the iFrame (hidden until called) at the bottom under your submit/cancel buttons, activate/show the frame on submit with a message "saving... / processing..." and if an error is returned, display it and style the frame accordingly.

Comment: Yes I like the idea of using a hidden iframe. Will be happy to accept as the answer.